# my search function is working properly with one word but with two words phrase that need a spacing it display nothing ex(My Name)

Tags: android, json, listview, search, android-activity

guys someone help me my search function is working  properly with one word but with two words phrase that need a spacing it display nothing ex(My Name).

This is the part where i do my ontext change functions.
Activity

```
                public class Builds extends ListActivity {


                private ProgressDialog pDialog;
                Button b4;
                EditText inputSearch;


                // URL to get contacts JSON
                private static String url = "http://computersolutions.comli.com/android_json.php";


                // JSON Node names

                private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
                private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
                private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
                private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
                private static final String TAG_SAMPLE = "sample";


                // contacts JSONArray
                JSONArray contacts = null;

                // Hash map for ListView
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList =
                new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.builds);

                b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReturn);

                b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                UserPage.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                });

                // Calling async task to get JSON
                new GetContacts().execute();
                }

                /*
                * Async task class to get JSON by making HTTP call
                */
                private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Showing progress dialog
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Builds.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Connecting to web server...");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
                } 



                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                // Creating service handler class instance
                ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

                // Making a request to URL and getting response
                String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

                if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);


                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                String sample = c.getString(TAG_SAMPLE);


                // temporary HashMap for single contact
                HashMap<String, String> contact =
                new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                contact.put(TAG_SAMPLE, sample);

                // adding contact to contact list
                contactList.add(contact);
                }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
                } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the URL!");
                }

                return null;
                }


                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                // Dismiss the progress dialog
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();

                // Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Builds.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item2,
                new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL,TAG_ID,TAG_SAMPLE},
                new int[] {R.id.name, R.id.email,R.id.id ,R.id.sample}
                );
                inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
                setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Text Watcher

```
                inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {
                        // When user changed the Text
                        TextView txt;
                        txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pprice);
                        String a = inputSearch.getText().toString();
                        txt.setText("Results for "+a+":");
                        String st = s.toString().trim();  
                        ((SimpleAdapter) adapter).getFilter().filter(st);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                            int arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
                    }
                });

                }

                }
                }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and especially http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. If you follow the advice in those links you will be **Much** more likely to get an answer and might even figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the trim() function which you are using removes the spaces from the String which you want to search.
So try removing the trim() function and see whether it works or not.